# Parse Error with InputStream into Document Builder parse()

Tags: java, inputstream

I am working on a Java program to display this Document as a string and I am getting the following error:

`The entity "nbsp" was referenced, but not declared.`

The Java code is:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
fDocBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

URL url = new URL(fServer + query);
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
connection.setRequestMethod("GET");

InputStream responseStream = connection.getInputStream();
Document response = fDocBuilder.parse(responseStream);
return response.toString();
```

How do I fix that?

Comment: Adding a bit more context to the question will help us help you. What is `connection`, what is `fDocBuilder`?

Comment: Please put the whole code here............ so that it's easy to analyze it

Comment: If you want to look at it, that's fine. You can get it [here](http://gls.agilix.com/js/docs/Samples/DlapSampleJava.zip). It's the file labeled Dlap.java - line 169 - 171 is what I'm having issues with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XML supports just a few entities, and `nbsp` is certainly not one of them. To make your code running you should declare a meaning of your entites in DTD.

You can add following declaration to document:

```
<!DOCTYPE html 
     PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" 
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
```

If you don't have any influence on a document, then you can use `EntityResolver2` which provides interface for this.

See: [EntityResolver2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/org/xml/sax/ext/EntityResolver2.html) - method `getExternalSubset`